# как правильно сделать CONCAT строк через terminal в postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

```
 id |  name  |      pwd       |      email       | gender 
:---+:-------+:--------------:+:----------------:+--------:
  1 | Vasya  | 21341234qwfsdf | mmm@mmail.com    | m
  2 | Alex   | 21341234       | mmm@gmail.com    | m
  3 | Alexey | qq21341234Q    | alexey@gmail.com | m
  4 | Helen  | MarryMeeee     | hell@gmail.com   | f
  5 | Jenny  | SmakeMyb       | eachup@gmail.com | f
  6 | Lora   | burn23         | tpicks@gmail.com | f

я создал таблицу и хочу получить из нее вот такой результат 

+:---------------------------------------------:+
| info                                          |
+:---------------------------------------------:+
| This is Vasya, he has email mmm@mmail.com     |
| This is Alex, he has email mmm@gmail.com      |
| This is Alexey, he has email alexey@gmail.com |
| This is Helen, she has email hell@gmail.com   |
| This is Jenny, she has email eachup@gmail.com |
| This is Lora, she has email tpicks@gmail.com  |

но я ещё не знаю как вывести сразу 6 строк и чтобы получился результат выше, чтобы парни писались через he, а девушки через she.
```

все что у меня пока получается это делать два запроса и выводить по три строки, и вручную менять he/she.
наверное в условии нужно как-то делать привязку к gender, но это не точно

```
select *, concat ('This is ', name, ', he has email ', email) as info from names where id>=1 and id<=3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант

```
select concat ('This is ', name, ', ',
       (CASE
           WHEN gender = 'm' THEN 'he'
           ELSE 'she'
       END),
 ' has email ', email) as info from names where id>=1 and id<=6;
```

Comment: выдает такую ошибку
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 5:        END as g),

Comment: уберите as g из запроса я просто точно не помню:) Да и скобки может вокруг CASE не нужны:) Должно работать

Comment: так и сделал, спасибо большое)
понял теперь что CASE задает условие

Comment: Именно, точнее варианты, WHEN может быть много